# UWP Kiosk mode open FileOpenPicker in F: drive

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10, kiosk

I am using Multi Kiosk (assigned access) mode to show my UWP apps in Windows 10 Version 1809.

I have requirement to open the FileOpenPicker dialog and select files in F: drive.

But in Kiosk mode it only allow to open known folders that I have added the capability.

I tried to add **broadFileSystemAccess**. Still it is not allowing to browse file in F drive.

Can we achieve this in Kiosk mode?

Comment: About the F: drive, can you tell us if it is a removable device or a disk?

Comment: It is physical hard drive. Not removable storage.

Comment: When you add broadFileSystemAccess, if you use `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"F:\...")`, can you get the file correctly?

Comment: Yes. I can read/write contents of file any location using code.But the file picker dialog not showing other drives.

Comment: It seems that the file picker has limits in kiosk mode. I suggest you still use `GetFileFromPathAsync()` to achieve it.